# Find the probability that the largest number appearing in a coupon is 9 out of coupons numbered 1 to 15

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$15$ coupons are numbered $1,2,3...,15$ respectively. $7$ coupons are selected at random one at a time with replacement. The probability that the largest number appearing in a selected coupon is $9$ ???

**Try**
The largest number will be $9$ if out of $7$ selected coupon one is numbered $9$ and the other $6$ are in between $1$ to $8$.The number $9$ can be choosen in any one place out the $7$ selected coupons. So there are $7$ ways I can choose $9$ and in each case other $6$ numbers can be choosen in $8^6$ ways. Hence the required probability is $\frac {7\times 8^6}{{15}^7}$
I know exactly the same problem is there in Stack. But my approach is completely different. And I want to know where is the mistake in this method.

Comment: Let $M$ denote the max of the coupons.  The probability that all are less than $i$ is $P(M≤i)=\left(\frac i{15}\right)^7$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: It seems you neglected the probability of selecting the $9$ exactly, which is $1/15.$

Comment: There could be multiple $9's$ which you have not accounted for

Comment: Indeed, you want there to be $1$ nine, and $6$ that are _less or equal_ than nine. The problem will become messy because you no longer will have control on where the $9$ falls. A better approach is to use @lulu's